# Programmatically make a continuous (forever) video feed (for free?)

Tags: video-streaming

What services and software might be required to simply:

Write some code that programmatically generates time-based media (presentations of picture, sound, and text and transitions between them) (probably using HTML/CSS/JS) and have it streamed continuously as a video (a la Ustream) that can be watched by thousands of viewers at once?

The key here is that it should really be able to run continuously without intervention for, like, a year, while I can, whenever I please, deploy new time-based-media-generating scripts to be used by the main video-generating program, either randomly, or in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is free, no-one will be giving you free bandwidth to stream your videos for years... Eigther they will show their ads in between or you will have to pay.

Thousands of viewers at once is too much for free, even if you set up your own streaming server and infrastructure, you will have to have a leased line or multiple T1 lines to stream.

If the above issues are not a concern, there are plenty of softwares out there in the market (search for TV software), these softwares can output video stream continously which u can pick and then stream.

Windows Media Encoder is a lightwiight option.